# Google custom search API with OAuth2

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-custom-search

Is it possible to get authorized for Google's custom search API with OAuth2 instead of using their `ClientLogin`, which would mean I'd need to build a whole UI to deal with user's login/password/captcha, plus I'm not a fan of inputting secure information like that on my own system. I'd rather rely on OAuth2 and login directly to Google

I've looked around but haven't been able to find anything for the scope part of the url eg `scope="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"` for authenticating with their Contacts API.

Note: I'm using Ruby to develop this.